# Switching empty Oracle 12c database to Unicode

Tags: oracle, encoding, oracle12c, datapump

I have Oracle 12c installed in a Ubuntu Linux development environment with NLS_CHARACTERSET = WE8MSWIN1252. I want to import a database using data pump that has AL32UTF8 encoding. Is there a convenient way (other than reinstalling Oracle) to either switch my Oracle to Unicode entirely (no need to worry about preserving existing data), or to somehow "locally" use Unicode encoding for the schemas that I import?

Comment: Almost always, the first thing to check is the Oracle documentation, in this case https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch11charsetmig.htm#NLSPG011  I am not sure about your concept of "empty" database. A database is never empty - don't forget the catalog tables, which are always present, and which also need to use a character set.

Comment: I recommend you reinstall the database.  There's a lot of bad advice on how to change a database character set.  Some of the buggiest databases I've had to manage were the result of a bad character set conversion.  (If it helps, you can blame the extra work on Oracle.  Despite the manual saying UTF8 is the best choice, their stupid installer didn't use UTF8 as the default until 12.2.)

Comment: In case of an "empty" database (whatever that means) a reinstall should be no big deal.

Comment: Unfortunately, installing Oracle on Ubuntu is quite inconvenient as Ubuntu is not officially supported.

Answer (score 0):

For converting a database to AL32UTF8 characterset, Oracle introduced the Database Migration Assistant for Unicode ([DMU](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DUMAG/toc.htm)) in version 12.1.

It is "convenient" as it is a GUI based tool which guides you through all the steps, at the same time it can be called "complex" as it requires a separate repository.